# Is it possible to initialize an std::array of unnamed structs?

Tags: c++

The below works:

```
struct
{
    int v;
} vals[] = { {1}, {2} };
```

Can I do the same thing but instead initialize an `std::array`?

**Edit since so many people are asking 'why'**

There are some very obvious workarounds (listed in the comments), but I only want to use the type once, so I don't really want it added to my current namespace. I could  use a tuple or something similar, but having the named values improves clarity. I don't need the c-array value if I am constructing an `std::array`, so I can't use decltype.

The cleanest solution that I *want* to do is:

```
struct
{
    int v;
} std::array vals = { {1}, {2} };
```

There is an element of academic interest as well - "is this possible in some way I hadn't though of?". Seems like not, so I'll likely use:

```
struct
{
    int v;
} c_array[] = {};

std::array<std::remove_reference_t<decltype(c_array[0])>, 2> arr = { {1}, {2} };
```

Comment: Have you tried `array<struct {int v}, 10>`?

Comment: @MatsPetersson That won't work.

Comment: `struct { int v; } foo; std::array<decltype(foo), 10> bar = {{{1},{2}}};`? But...why do you need to do this?

Comment: struct unnamed { int v; }; std::array<unnamed, 2> vals = {{1],{2]}};

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Hmm, if you name a struct unnamed, is it still unnamed? ;)

Comment: `std::array` requires a type parameter. To refer to a user-defined type, you need to declare something.

Comment: I'm really interested in a use-case for this....

Comment: @T.C. Upvoted for _Why do you need this?_ A practitioner would hardly need it; it seems to be a purely language lawyer question.

Comment: Your edit's solution creates a zero-sized array.

Comment: Yep, that's by design - I don't want to take up the space of the type; I just want the type.  Realistically maybe naming the struct is cleaner after all :P

Comment: ...which is ill-formed

Comment: @Rollie I don't think a type takes up any (memory) space at runtime (i.e. barring RTTI) but only disk space due to the source code containing the lexical type name :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason you can't do:

```
std::array<struct {int v}, 10> arr;
```

is because of the following rule from N4140:

> §7.1.6/3 [...] A *type-specifier-seq* shall not define a class or
>   enumeration unless it appears in the *type-id* of an *alias-declaration*
>   (7.1.3) that is not the *declaration* of a
>   *template-declaration*.

Since a template type argument is specified using a *type-id*, and a *type-id* contains a *type-specifier-seq*, it can't be the definition of a class.

You could use a typedef, but:

> §9.1/5 A *typedef-name* (7.1.3) that names a class type, or a
>   cv-qualified version thereof, is also a *class-name*. [...]

I would go with the suggestion by [T.C.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28495119/is-it-possible-to-initialize-an-stdarray-of-unnamed-structs/28495626#comment45310348_28495119):

```
struct { int v; } foo; std::array<decltype(foo), 10> bar = {{{1},{2}}};
```

Comment: That exception is referring to `using T = struct { int v; };` - an *alias-declaration* that's not part of an alias template declaration. The reason is that they wanted an exact match between `using` s and `typedef`s.